# How to verify if props is valid element OR functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, jsx, custom-component

I've some problem to verify if `props` passing to `CustomComponent` is a valid `react jsx` especially in `React Native`

Let say my `CustomComponent` is:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

export default CustomComponent = props => {
  const RenderHeader = () => {
    if (React.isValidElement(props.headerComponent))
      return props.headerComponent;
    else return null;
  };
  
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, ...props.style }}>
      <RenderHeader />
    </View>
  );
};
```

I want to use my `CustomComponent` something like this:

```js
const Header = () => {
  return <Text style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>What is your birthday?</Text>;
};
/** <Header/> rendered */
1. <CustomComponent headerComponent={<Header/>} />

/** <Header/> not render */
2. <CustomComponent headerComponent={()=> <Header/>} />

/** Header not render */
3. <CustomComponent headerComponent={Header} />
```

How to let my `CustomComponent` accept two more syntax above and render properly?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```js
const CustomComponent = props => {
  const RenderHeader = () => {
      return props.headerComponent instanceof Function ? props.headerComponent() : props.headerComponent
  };
  
  return (
    <div style={{ flex: 1, ...props.style }}>
      <RenderHeader />
    </div>
  );
};

const Header = () => {
  return <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>What is your birthday?</p>;
};

const Example = () => {
    return (
        <div>
          <CustomComponent headerComponent={<Header/>} />
          <CustomComponent headerComponent={()=> <Header/>} />
          <CustomComponent headerComponent={Header} />
        </div>
    );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Example />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: with those condition if i use `<CustomComponent headerComponent={()=> console.log('this is called')} />` the `console` still run, which is i don't want it